# Developing ASP.NET on Windows Server 2008 - Good Idea?

Tags: development-environment

I was wondering if developing ASP.NET applications on Windows Server 2008 was a good idea, and if not why not.

At work we have to use Windows Server 2008 as our desktop OS for developing (as it is closer to the production environment apparently). Using a server OS as your development environment doesn't seem right to me.

Does anyone know if this is good or bad practice?

EDIT - How about performance? I imagine they'd be pretty much the same though.

Comment: "At work we have to use Windows Server 2008 as our desktop OS for developing " - your licensing costs must be high?

Comment: given that 99% of the devs out there developing ASP.NET apps do it on something other than Windows Server 2008, makes you wonder?

Comment: We all have MSDN licences.... which we can use on our home PCs for working from home... one of the few good things about working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it.

In some ways, it is good practice, in particular if your servers run the same OS and version (so you can find out certain issues early on).

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a problem with developing in that environment.  Visual Studio  works well on Windows Server 2008.  On the other hand, I have never run into a problem with developing on a workstation OS (XP, Vista, Win 7) and deploying to a server.  I suppose that there might be some scenario where developing directly on the server OS is better, but I cannot think of one.

One of my developers is running with Server 2008 as a desktop OS (I do not).  She has not had any trouble with Visual Studio.  But, she has had many issues (Sorry I do not remember the specifics) with other aspects of the computing environment, things like Outlook, Word, Project, etc.  Not that they do not work, just annoyances that pop up occasionally.

Hope this helps,
Jim

Comment: I haven't had any problems with other programs. Though outlook seems to like picking an office icon at random to use in the task bar.